# python2.4.3: format bug?

Tags: python, floating-point, python-2.4

Here is an example:

```
>>> "%.2f" % 0.355
'0.35'
>>> "%.2f" % (float('0.00355') *100)
'0.36'
```

Why they give different result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a format bug. This is just floating point arithmetic. Look at the values underlaying your format commands:

```
In [18]: float('0.00355')
Out[18]: 0.0035500000000000002

In [19]: float('0.00355')*100
Out[19]: 0.35500000000000004

In [20]: 0.355
Out[20]: 0.35499999999999998
```

The two expressions create different values.

I don't know if it's available in 2.4 but you can use the decimal module to make this work:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> "%.2f" % (decimal.Decimal('0.00355')*100)
'0.35'
```

The decimal module treats floats as strings to keep arbitrary precision.

Comment: I had thought of the same, even this were, '%.2f' should have pickd up 0.35 in both cases, isn't it?

Comment: @Senthil, I don't know old style formatting so well but it looks like the values are being rounded instead of truncated. I get the same the same behavior in 2.6.5 and 3.1.2

Comment: @Senthil:  No;  in the first case (`0.355`), the actual number stored is, thanks to the usual problems with binary floating-point, just a smidgen under `0.355`, so it gets rounded down.  In the second case, the result of `0.00355 * 100` (no need for the `float` call here) is a tiny amount larger than `0.355`, so gets rounded up.

Comment: Indeed, floating-point formatting using `%` rounds rather than truncates;  in versions of Python prior to 2.7, it takes this behaviour straight from the corresponding C `sprintf` behaviour.  In more recent versions of Python, the conversion is implemented within the Python core, but still has the same 'round-to-nearest' behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Because, as with *all* floating point "inaccuracy" questions, not every real number can be represented in a limited number of bits.

Even if we were to go nuts and have 65536-bit floating point formats, the number of numbers between 0 and 1 is still, ... well, infinite :-)

What's almost certainly happening is that the first one is slightly *below* 0.355 (say, 0.3549999999999) while the second is slightly *above* (say, 0.3550000001).

See [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for some further reading on the subject.

A good tool to play with to see how floating point numbers work is [Harald Schmidt's excellent on-line converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html). This was so handy, I actually implemented my own C# one as well, capable of handling both IEEE754 single *and* double precision.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic with floating point numbers is often inaccurate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems